# Hidden Code Samples

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I just wrote a response to a pretty rudimentary question and it seems to me like the poster/reader might benefit from not having the code thrown in their face right away but by having helpful tips and comments and then being able to reveal useable code if they can't implement it themselves.  Seeing as how these are already both features (hidden block quotes ">!" and multiline code) is there any chance we can combine these?

Comment: This site is not trying to cater to "nudging in the right direction" questions.  Either answer or don't and vote appropriately.

Answer (score 13):

If you're having trouble expressing an answer without a smattering of code when you *know* a smattering of code is going to be the least helpful, you should revisit how you're expressing your answer.

[Here's an example of an answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18804082/1079354) for what I'd consider a rudimentary question; in it, the OP has expressed what trouble they're going through and what their code is and why it's not working.  So, instead of giving them *just* the code that would fix it, I also take the time to explain why their code was wrong and what could be done to make it better.

I don't feel that hiding the code would convey the teaching portion any better, since if they know that the answer to all of the things is just available in a slightly less accessible copy-and-paste form, then they're just going to take that and run.  It's better to actually guide a person along and explain their error rather than give them *just* the answer; think about what'll benefit them in the long run here.

Answer (score -10):

One way you could do it is maybe stick the code in a JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet which is to the right of the insert image button. You'd just alter this line that's generated in the answer:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Just set `hide` to true and then they would have to click on the show code snippet link. Though you might lose the fancy syntax highlighting from the regular code block, but no one cares about this.....right? *gets bricked*

---

Now, yes, I agree that throwing code at people's faces probably won't help them,

1) since the only real way to throw code at someone is to throw the system at them....and that hurts

2) in the end we really want to [teach them how to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

What you have posted (assumingly) as you first answer is better than some I see from some users who just go *"try this"* or *"use this code"* followed by a code dump. Worse yet, I have seen a user who's posted only a code dump with zero explanation of what they have changed (I won't link, otherwise I might invoke the Meta Effect).

At least you explain you code, why you would use `with` `as` and the logic in your loop. I have never used Python and I understood what you was trying to achieve there in your code quicker than what I would have if I was just reading a code block.

Would your answer be improved if you hid the code block above? Not really, since if the asker just copied and pasted it like a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) they might miss out of the fact you use `words = file.read().split()` which populates your `words` variable for your loop.

Would future answers be improves by this? Probably not because you have this "run code snippet" button and remember that when you post an answer you not only are trying to help the asker, but also anyone else who arrives at your answer with the same or similar problem (if they are doing their research first). If they aren't familiar with Stack Overflow's features they might get confused thinking that "run code snippet" might actually run it which unless it's JavaScript/HTML/CSS and in the right spots it won't.

Comment: But for non-runnable code? That's just bad.

Comment: @AndrewL. i know. quite sure the Javascript/HTML/CSS Snippet was never designed to be used with anything other than Javascript/HTML/CSS Snippet

Comment: Of course it's not. Telling someone to use code snippets to hide non-runnable code is a bad suggestion. It clutters a post and has no point at all.